# AWS java sdk - SqsClient.create() fails without throwing an exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm having an issue with my call to SqsClient.create() failing.  In one case, I was able to recreate this by setting the wrong AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY value in my environmental vars.  In other cases, I don't know why it fails.  The issue is, instead of throwing an exception, it seems to just fail silently and I end up getting some other problems down the road because of it. And I can't troubleshoot it because it never goes into the catch block! I orignally was just catching AwsServiceException and SdkClientException, but after my initial problems, I added a catch-all Exception as well to my try-catch block, but even then, when it fails it still doesn't go into the last Exception catch block for some reason.  What can be the cause of this?  I am scratching my head trying to figure it out.

```
      try {
         sqsClient = SqsClient.create();
         snsClient = SnsClient.create();

      } catch (final AwsServiceException ex) {
         //do something
      } catch (final SdkClientException ex) {
         //do something
      } catch (Exception e) {
         //do something
      }
```

Comment: What happens if you catch `Throwable` instead of `Exception`?

Comment: What does "failure" mean? Is it a case where the queue is not ready for us when you try to use it? Or something else?

Comment: @stdunbar thanks, catching Throwable did catch the error.  Seems like an issue with one of the dependencies.  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/938) (although that's V1 of the SDK library).  Do you have an older Apache HTTP Client library that's on your build path?

Comment: I do.  Seems like that should solve the problem, but the weird thing is, after I replaced the existing httpcore.jar and httpclient.jar files with newer versions, it's still failing for some reason, but I'm back to square one because it's not being caught in my throwable catch block anymore :(.